# all.moments function weird outcome

Tags: r, statistics

I want to calculate the n-th moment of a distribution. I am trying to using all.moments function of library 'moments' in R. I have tested all.moments in this way:

```
 library(moments)
 r<-rnorm(10000)
 rr<-all.moments(r,order.max=4)
 rr

 [1]  1.000000000  0.002403360  0.962201478 -0.022694670  2.852696159
```

This seems to me that it's not true, cause i know that the 3-th and 4-th moment must be 0 in a normal distribution.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third moment is the **skewness**. You are correct: for a normal distribution this is zero. Since you are only sampling from a normal distribution, your results will be approximately zero, which it is.

The fourth order moment is the **kurtosis**. For a normal distribution this is 3σ^4. In this case, σ is 1, so your result should be 3, which it is.

---

To improve the accuracy of your estimate, improve the sample size. For a sample of 1e7 observations:

```
> library(moments)
> r <- rnorm(1e7)
> all.moments(r,order.max=4)
[1] 1.0000000000 0.0004028138 0.9995373115 0.0007276404 2.9976881271
```

Answer (score 1):

Because that's only true in expectation and not precisely, and because the higher moments have large variances?

(See @Andrie's answer as well, for why the fourth moment (`V5` below) is not even close to zero.)

```
> library(moments)
> R <- t(replicate(50,all.moments(rnorm(1e4),order.max=4)))
> summary(R)
       V1          V2                  V3               V4            
 Min.   :1   Min.   :-0.024921   Min.   :0.9714   Min.   :-0.0987174  
 1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:-0.009527   1st Qu.:0.9911   1st Qu.:-0.0341950  
 Median :1   Median : 0.001021   Median :0.9994   Median : 0.0067138  
 Mean   :1   Mean   :-0.001047   Mean   :1.0006   Mean   :-0.0002613  
 3rd Qu.:1   3rd Qu.: 0.004711   3rd Qu.:1.0147   3rd Qu.: 0.0299731  
 Max.   :1   Max.   : 0.023356   Max.   :1.0398   Max.   : 0.1283456  
       V5       
 Min.   :2.775  
 1st Qu.:2.921  
 Median :3.005  
 Mean   :3.007  
 3rd Qu.:3.092  
 Max.   :3.325
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, working in python, and I think that the limited precision of floating point arithmetic on a computer, esp. with powers of large numbers, is also not helping. I'll cut and paste my Python code and the results I get. This code tries to compute the first 20 moments of a standard normal. In short, I think it's not easy to compute high order moments of a distribution numerically, "high order" meaning here greater than 10 or so. In a separate experiment, I tried to reduce the variance I get on the 18th moment by drawing more and more samples, but that wasn't practical either given my "ordinary" computer.

```
N = 1000000
w = np.random.normal(size=N).astype("float128")

for i in range(20):
    print i, mean(w**i) # simply computing the mean of the data to the power of i
```

Gives you:

```
0 1.0
1 0.000342014729693
2 1.00124397377
3 0.000140133725668
4 3.00334304532
5 0.00506625342217
6 15.0227401941
7 0.0238395446636
8 105.310071549
9 -0.803915389936
10 948.126995798
11 -34.8374820713
12 10370.6527554
13 -1013.23231638
14 132288.117911
15 -26403.9090218
16 1905267.02257
17 -658590.680295
18 30190439.4783
19 -16101299.7354
```

But the correct moments are: 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 15, 0, 105, 0, 945, 0, 10395, 0, 135135, 0, 2027025, 0, 34459425, 0, 654729075.

Comment: it's not a matter of numerical imprecision: it's that the variance of the higher moments explodes.

Comment: But here, I'm giving myself a large number N of random numbers from the standard normal, compute e.g., their 18th power, then the average of this. In this procedure, if I increase N, shouldn't I get closer and closer to the true value of the 18th moment?

Comment: Yes, but you have to increase it a *lot*.

Comment: Yes. I tried, you have to increase it way too much to be practical. Even at 1e10 samples, the variance on the 18th moment is something like 1e27. So, I'm not sure it's really practical on an average computer.